# Excel How to combine all rows having the same id number into one column for a huge dataset?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, combine

I have a 350K of rows in an excel file. I need to combine all rows having a unique id to the same row as following:

```
Unique ID    |    Mbr ID    |    Name
1            |    10227     |    ABC1
1            |    254112    |    ABC2
2            |     3688     |    XYZ1
2            |     1123     |    XYZ2
2            |     9800     |    XYZ3
```

For a reason, we need to combine fields having the same unique id into one like the following:

```
Unique ID    |    Mbr ID    |    Name    Unique ID    |    Mbr ID    |    Name    Unique ID    |    Mbr ID    |    Name
1            |    10227     |    ABC1    1            |    254112    |    ABC2
2            |     3688     |    XYZ1    2            |     1123     |    XYZ2    2            |     9800     |    XYZ3
```

We tried using `vLookup` but it seems to take a long time and in most case it's not working at all. Any idea on how to do it?

P.S. We tried a tool called `Kutools` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Is this a one-time task? or should it be done regularly?

Comment: @Akina it is a one time task

Comment: You need code to get the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the source data posessed on the worksheet named as Sheet1 occupied A1:Cxxxxxx range.

Create a worksheed names Sheet2 - the pivotted data will be placed into it.

Sort source data by column A (Unique ID).

Then run the next macro:

```
Sub doPivot()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim vals()
Dim i As Integer
Dim uid
Dim crow As Integer
Dim ccol As Integer

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
vals = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
    If vals(i, 1) = uid Then
        ccol = ccol + 3
    Else
        crow = crow + 1
        ccol = 1
    End If
    uid = vals(i, 1)
    sh.Cells(crow, ccol) = vals(i, 1)
    sh.Cells(crow, ccol + 1) = vals(i, 2)
    sh.Cells(crow, ccol + 2) = vals(i, 3)
Next i
End Sub
```

Finally grad-over the header to left if needed.

Comment: Please note that I have 10 field per row, not 3, but for simplicity I said it is 3 columns.

Comment: Edit code, what a problem?

Comment: look, I have 150K. It only run on 20K and exit with an error of `Overflow`. Should I split my excel to 20K rows sheets?

Comment: @alim1990  try to replace `integer` to `long`

Comment: Change iterational variables definitions from *Integer* to *Long* (`i`, and, maybe, `crow`).